# ember-cli disable file versioning in production build

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

When I run `ember build --production` it adds versioning to each file type. This is a problem for me as I have a compilation script that compiles the ember up then takes the file out for further processing.

How can I disable versioning of file names in production?

Comment: are u referring to fingerprinting of the files?

Comment: yes the hash it adds in the name of the file

Comment: http://www.ember-cli.com/#fingerprinting-and-cdn-urls

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit you brocfile like below.

```
var app = new EmberApp({
  fingerprint: {
    enabled: false
  }
});
```